# how to use a loop on jquery to shorten my current code?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a website that consist of 10 thumbnails, and i used php to query mysql to retrieve the data, i successfully retrieve and display it one by one, now i want to shorten my code but i need some guidance..

HTML

```
<div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="" src2="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped10.jpg" src3="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped1.jpg" alt="portfolio"author-img="images/portfolio/huizhong/huizhong.jpg" resume="images/portfolio/huizhong/resume.pdf" work1-title="World Within" work1-desc="Capturing the world within your phone" work2-title="Digital Painting" work2-desc="Digital painting of my favourite character" work3-title="Yoona" work3-desc="Digital painting of my favourite kpop artiste">
                    <h2 class="caption">Du Hui Zhong<br />Featured Portfolio1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped2.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Dai Sao Ke<br />Featured Portfolio2</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped3.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Grace Foo<br />Featured Portfolio3</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped4.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Leonard Wee<br />Featured Portfolio4</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped5.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Shaun Koo<br />Featured Portfolio5</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped6.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Jane Sia<br />Featured Portfolio6</h2>    
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped7.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Gospal Ahmad<br />Featured Portfolio7</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped8.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Mathew Goh<br />Featured Portfolio8</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped11.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Berlinda Chan<br />Featured Portfolio9</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="images/portfolio/Cropped Pics/FS/cropped12.jpg">
                    <h2 class="caption">Joanne Koo<br />Featured Portfolio10</h2>
                </div>
// 10 thumbnails holder
```

php

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Specialisation = "class1o2"';

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $links[] = array(
            "links" => $row["Link"],
            "caption" => $row["Name"],
        );                  
    }
    echo json_encode($links);   
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "CMS/PHP/displayFeatThumbs.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(0)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[0].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(0) .caption").html("<span>" + data[0].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");

            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(1)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[1].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(1) .caption").html("<span>" + data[1].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(2)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[2].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(2) .caption").html("<span>" + data[2].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(3)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[3].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(3) .caption").html("<span>" + data[3].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");
            alert(data[3].links);
            alert(data[2].links);


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(4)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[4].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(4) .caption").html("<span>" + data[4].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(5)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[5].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(5) .caption").html("<span>" + data[5].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(6)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[6].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(6) .caption").html("<span>" + data[6].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(7)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[7].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(7) .caption").html("<span>" + data[7].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(8)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[8].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(8) .caption").html("<span>" + data[8].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");


            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(9)").children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[9].links);
            $(".img_thumb_holder:nth(9) .caption").html("<span>" + data[9].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");
        }
    });
```

as you can see on my jquery i just repeat it for the rest of the image holder i want to show, i know i can use a loop to do this but i am not sure how. Another issue is that on my php, everything will work smoothly if i have 1 image per user stored, but if i have 2 image on 1 user, it will displayed out all the works of that user before it goes on to the next user, how can i do it so that it only retrieve 1 image per user instead of all? Thanks!

Comment: You know what a loop is right?

Comment: what is the `:nth` selector

Comment: look at [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: @Arun, all my image share the same class, so i use :nth selector to specify that i want that holder to display a certain image, once i'm done with that holder i move on to the next holder using :nth

Comment: @robbmj i do, but i'm very weak at loop so often got confused.

Comment: Well copy and pasting someone else's code is not going to make you a stronger programmer. Go struggle with the problem for a while.

Comment: well i wouldn't mind referencing from an example if u willing to show that is related to what i want to do so that if i understand it will be good as well @Robbmj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this....

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "CMS/PHP/displayFeatThumbs.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.img thumb_holder img').each(function(index, element) {
                   // Work out the data to set
                   var imageUrl = "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms" + data[index].links;
                   var captionHtml = "<span>" + data[index].caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>"
                   // Now apply this to the elements
                   $(element)
                      .attr("src", imageUrl);
                   $(element)
                      .next()
                      .html(captionHtml);
            });
         });
```

Comment: i understand this more better than the other answer, going to try it out. The index and element that u insert as parameters will dynamically increase after each loop am i right to say that?

Comment: Yes, the function will be called once for each element in the loop, with the index and element parameters changing on each call.

Comment: ok i understand about the index part, but for the element you did $(element).children, for each run wouldn't it be just for example 1.children 2.children? Or are you just showing me an example so i actually need to make it work out as :nth(1).children :nth(2).children?

Comment: @Devon: I  was being careless. It should be the child items you're iterating over. I'll fix it now.

Comment: good thing i understood your code enough.. The only unsure thing was the parameters but now that i do understand it is good! Going to test it out now!

Comment: @Devon - I've fixed it so it iterates over the multiple images, and uses `next` to access the subsequent caption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65183/discussion-between-andrew-shepherd-and-devon).

Answer (score 0):

You can create html view section from PHP then return it to ajax function.

**PHP**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $html_data = '<div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
                    <img class="img_thumb" src="' . $row["Link"] . '">
                    <h2 class="caption">' . $row["Name"] . '</h2>
                </div>';
}
echo json_encode($html_data);
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "CMS/PHP/displayFeatThumbs.php",
    success: function (data) {
        //$('.img_thumb_holder').append(data);
        $('.img_thumb_holder').html(data);
    }
});
```

`$('.img_thumb_holder').append(data);` can be used if you need to retain old images and new image list will update at bottom.

```
$('.img_thumb_holder').html(data);
```

can be used so that this will replace old imaged with new.
In your code data is looping on both server side and client side.

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback, do:

```
var container = $('.img_thumb_holder');

data.forEach(function (item, i) {
  var div = container.append('<div>')
      div.append('<img class="img_thumb" src="'+data[i].links+'">')
      div.append('<h1 class="caption">'+data[i].caption+'</h1>') 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like

```
//cache the holder elements
var $holders = $(".img_thumb_holder");
$.each(data, function (i, dt) {
    //access the hodler at index i
    var $holder = $holders.eq(i);
    //set the corresponding values inside each holder
    $holder.children("img").attr("src", "http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + dt.links);
    $holder.find(".caption").html("<span>" + dt.caption + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/><span class='spacer'></span>" + "Portfolio" + "</span>");
})
```